# load json file in nodejs/express app into d3

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, d3.js

I have an express app and I want to load json-data from the folder `public` into d3 (version 4).

My folder structure looks like this:

```
public
|-myData.json
view
|-index.jade
app.js
```

The json data I want to load with d3:

```
{
  {
    "name": "Maria",
    "age": 30
  }, {
    "name": "Fred",
    "age": 50
  }, {
    "name": "Francis",
    "age": 12
  }
}
```

This is my index.jade file:

```
extends layout
block content
  script(src='javascripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js')
  script(src='javascripts/d3.min.js')
  script.
    $(document).ready(function() {
      d3.json("myData.json", function(data) {
        console.log("d ", data);
      });
    });
```

In app.js I said that I want to serve static files:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

In the console it always says: `d  null`

Update:
I now changed the path to

```
"d3.json("../myData.json", function(data)"
```

Looking into the network tab, I can see that it loads the file successfully. But in the console it would still print "`null`"

Update 2:
It was because of my JSON - data that was invalid. ^^

```
{
    "content": [

        {
            "name": "Maria",
            "age": 30
        }, {
            "name": "Fred",
            "age": 50
        }, {
            "name": "Francis",
            "age": 12
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: "myData.json 404 xhr d3.min.js:6 1.2 KB 40 ms ". It can't be loaded resp. it's not found. I activated CORS on Chrome. @SLaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you point to the `public` folder in the first argument of `d3.json` *in respect* to where express is statically hosting the files.

```
...
d3.json("../myData.json", function(data) {
        console.log("d ", data);
      });
    });
```

Update: Edited answer to correct directory reference. Also be sure `myData.json` is a valid json file! :)

Comment: I tried this too. But that's not it. If I would do that, it would say in the console: "d3.min.js:6 GET http://localhost:3000/public/myData.json 404"

Comment: Ah, perhaps it's this line `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static('public'));` 
Try changing it to `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { index: 'index.jade' }));`

Comment: Nope. Before it called the index.jade already. So, it could find it before also. And it can also load the json file. But somehow d3 doesn't notice it. :/

Comment: Ah, damn... mind posting what data is in `myData.json`?

Comment: lol. That was it! My JSON file was invalid. XD. If you change your answer and include the valid JSON part, then I'll select your answer as the correct one! Thanks for giving me the hint. Spend nearly a day on that. XD

Comment: Updated! Glad I could help :)